# Scope of a WinRT share contract

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

Hi how do I control the scope of a share contract?

I have an WinRT app which takes advantage of sharing a file. I would like to have controle of what applications are available.

Right now I can see Mail, Skydrive and my own app. But I would like to disable my own app from the target app list for the share contract. Or add some custom things to it...

Any pointers or resoureces how to do that would be great...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"If your app has content to share, your app is a share source. If your app can receive content from other apps, then it’s a share target. Of course, apps can be both at once!

Note: If your app is both source and target for a particular data format, then it appears by default in the list of share targets each time people share from your app. Sometimes this is great, and sometimes it’s a little silly to share with yourself. If it’s silly, then you should display an error message prompting the user to select a different target app. "

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465251.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You, as the developer of an app which is a share source, can't control which apps make an acceptable target.  The OS will just find what share target apps match the type of data that you're sharing (like unformatted text, images, files, URIs, etc.) and make those available to share to.

But, as an end user, you can choose to disable an app from the target app list for the share contract.  Open the Settings charm and select "Change PC settings" from the bottom.  Select "Share" on the left-hand sidebar, and then under "Use these apps to share" on the right, find the app that you want to remove from the share target list and set its toggle to "Off".

Comment: The problem here is more one of usability: it usually doesn't make sense for an app to share data with itself.